# Show customers several times

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tabs where i need to combine the data, one tab contains a list of customer numbers that has a subscription on a package. The same customer can subscribe to the same package several times

Subscriptions

```
11  100
11  102
11  105
11  108
11  110
11  120
11  132
11  137
11  143
11  145
11  147
11  154
11  154
11  154
11  154
```

Customer

```
141 3   User141 Address Zip Town    
142 3   User142 Address Zip Town    
143 3   User143 Address Zip Town    
144 3   User144 Address Zip Town    
145 3   User145 Address Zip Town    
146 3   User146 Address Zip Town    
147 3   User147 Address Zip Town    
148 10  User148 Address Zip Town    
149 10  User149 Address Zip Town    
150 3   User150 Address Zip Town    
151 3   User151 Address Zip Town    
152 3   User152 Address Zip Town    
154 4   User154 Address Zip Town    
155 3   User155 Address Zip Town
```

I have been using filter to combine the two tables

```
=filter(Customer!A2:I; compare(Customer!A2:A;'Subscriptions'!B2:B;0))
```

But it only shows the entry 154 one time. Is there any way i it can be shown several times?

Comment: Is Compare() a standard Sheets function? Also, can you edit your question to include the column headers and also give an example of the desired output?